# Structure {page_url} variables still pointing to staging site after deploying to production

Tags: structure, url, server-migration

This question is also on StackOverflow. Sorry for repeating...

I've just moved an ExpressionEngine (v.2.5.3) stage site to the production server. The site uses Structure and Publisher add-ons.

Everything went well except that **all the hyperlinks using `{page_url}` are pointed to the stage site and not to the new site.**

I'm using **`{page_url}`** to call Structure entries.

However when I use `{path=""}` or `{url_title_path={segment_1}}` for instance the URLs are OK. It is only when using {page_url} that they kept pointed to the stage site.

I tried `{page_uri}`, which works, but then the language prefixes from Publisher get lost.

I run REElocate add-on and then checked:

- Admin > General Configuration > URL to the root directory
- Main index.php file, for any overrides to site_url
- Main config.php file for site_url variable overrides
- I checked all the Basepath to Template File Directory, the base_url, Also clean all caches,etc.

I went to check all the database SQL tables and: exp_files and publisher_log tables show staging paths not the new ones...

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I used to have issues like this then I started using a DRY config.php file. I would strongly recommend doing the same. My first config.php file was based on the one from this NetTuts article, ["Apply the DRY Principle to Build Websites With ExpressionEngine 2"](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/apply-the-dry-principle-to-build-websites-with-expressionengine-2/). If you set this up right you won't need to mess with REElocate anymore.

If you do use this approach and you still have problems, clear your cache and resave the entries. If the problem STILL persists then you might need to go into the SQL manually and fix the paths and hope they don't resurface.

**update**
Now that I'm in the office and have a couple minutes I can share my default config file (the database.php file is the same as the one from the article).

The biggest change from the NetTuts article is the use of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] instead of $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] because I tend to setup the staging server as a subdomain on the clients production server. This is to ensure that PHP and MySQL setting issues are caught early on and relying on IP addresses is difficult at best when doing this. Plus it's more human readable so you know what the development, staging, and production servers are. I am also a single developer so I don't setup a local production server where multiple devs can sync their efforts. You can easily add one by duplicating one of the switch cases.

If you want to learn more about some of the other hidden config variables in this config file, or others you can add at your own discretion, I would recommend this [page](http://devot-ee.com/ee-config-vars) on devot-ee. Te EE docs cover some variables but this page documents previously undocumented one that can be very useful.

I should also note that this is by far the only DRY config.php setup around. [Focus Lab LLC’s EE Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config/blob/master/readme.textile) is a very competent setup for doing the same thing and it sits above the web root which makes it easier to find and edit. Another popular approach is [NSM Config Bootstrap](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-config-bootstrap). To each their own. I decided to start with something basic and add to is while I learn more about what's really going on under the hood.

```
/* Environmental Variables
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
switch ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) {

    // development
    case 'mysite.dev' :
    $db['expressionengine']['hostname'] = "";
    $db['expressionengine']['username'] = "";
    $db['expressionengine']['password'] = "";
    $db['expressionengine']['database'] = "";
    break;

    // staging
    // case 'staging.mysite.com' :
    // $db['expressionengine']['hostname'] = "";
    // $db['expressionengine']['username'] = "";
    // $db['expressionengine']['password'] = "";
    // $db['expressionengine']['database'] = "";
    // break;

    // live
    // case 'mysite.com' :
    // $db['expressionengine']['hostname'] = "";
    // $db['expressionengine']['username'] = "";
    // $db['expressionengine']['password'] = "";
    // $db['expressionengine']['database'] = "";
    // break;

}

/* Universal Variables
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$config['app_version'] = "253";
$config['license_number'] = "1111-2222-3333-4444";
$config['debug'] = "1";
$config['install_lock'] = "";
$config['system_folder'] = "system";
$config['admin_file'] = "admin.php";
$config['doc_url'] = "http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/";
$config['is_system_on'] = "y";
$config['cookie_prefix'] = "";
$config['site_name'] = "Default EE install";
$config['allow_extensions'] = "y";
$config['enable_db_caching'] = "y";
$config['debug'] = "1";
$config['daylight_savings'] = date('I') ? 'y' : 'n'; // Autodetect DST
$config['cp_session_ttl'] = 3600; // Keep admins logged in for one hour! (in seconds)

/* General Path Settings
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$config['site_index'] = "";
$config['site_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['server_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
// $config['cp_url'] = $config['site_url']."/".$config['system_folder']; // use if keeping system within root
$config['cp_url'] = $config['site_url']."/".$config['admin_file']; // use if moving system one level above root

/* Universal database connection settings
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$active_group = 'expressionengine';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['expressionengine']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['expressionengine']['dbprefix'] = "exp_";
$db['expressionengine']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['expressionengine']['swap_pre'] = "exp_";
$db['expressionengine']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['expressionengine']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['expressionengine']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
$db['expressionengine']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['expressionengine']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['expressionengine']['cachedir'] = $config['cp_url']."/expressionengine/cache/db_cache/";

/* Member directory paths and urls
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$config['avatar_url'] = $config['site_url']."/images/avatars/uploads/";
$config['avatar_path'] = $config['server_path']."/images/avatars/uploads/";
$config['photo_url'] = $config['site_url']."/images/member_photos/";
$config['photo_path'] = $config['server_path']."/images/member_photos/";
$config['sig_img_url'] = $config['site_url']."/images/signature_attachments/";
$config['sig_img_path'] = $config['server_path']."/images/signature_attachments/";
$config['prv_msg_upload_path'] = $config['server_path']."/images/pm_attachments/";

/* Misc directory paths and urls
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$config['theme_folder_url'] = $config['site_url']."/themes/";
$config['theme_folder_path'] = $config['server_path']."/themes/";

/* File directory paths and urls
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// $config['upload_preferences'] = array(
//     1 => array(
//         'name'        => 'name of directory',
//         'server_path' => $config['server_path']."/assets/path/to/directory/",
//         'url'         => $config['site_url']."/assets/path/to/directory"
//     )
// );

/* Templates Preferences
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// $config['save_tmpl_files'] = "y";
// $config['tmpl_file_basepath'] = $config['server_path']."/templates/";
$config['site_404'] = "404/index";
$config['strict_urls'] = "y";
$config['hidden_template_indicator'] = "_";
$config['autosave_interval_seconds'] = "99999";
$config['word_separator'] = "underscore";

// END EE config items
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a Structure problem ... Admin > General and your paths are correct?

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have e.g. MAMP running? Maybe there is something left in the local cache from your stage_site

Comment: Kaspar - This would be better as a comment rather than an answer, since you are just clarifying things.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resaving the entries?

Is it also a problem for newly created entries?

Otherwise you could do a mass find and replace on the database via Tools > Data > Search and Replace

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't swear to it but I seem to recall that `{page_url}` when used inside say a WYSIWYG editor will actually be rendered as the full-path on saving of the entry.

I believe that's why I now never use anything else but relative URL's for content.

Also as James asked, does it happen on new entries also ?